# ms access syntax error invalid column specification (#0)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I am doing a union of two queries.

The queries run individually without an issue yet the union throws up this query. Any ideas?

The Query is

SELECT CStr([REFERENCE]) AS CostID,CSng([RATE]) AS HRates FROM [Qry 1 Project Budget pt1 labour rates] 
UNION ALL SELECT CStr([REFERENCE]),CSng([Rate]) FROM [Qry 1 Project Budget pt2 3rd party];

access 2007

Comment: show us your table schema.

Answer (score 1):

Both `CStr()` and `CSng()` will throw an error with Null.  Check whether any of your `[REFERENCE]` and `[RATE]` values are Null.

```sql
SELECT
    [REFERENCE],
    [RATE]
FROM [Qry 1 Project Budget pt1 labour rates]
WHERE [REFERENCE] Is Null OR [RATE] Is Null
UNION ALL
SELECT
    [REFERENCE],
    [Rate]
FROM [Qry 1 Project Budget pt2 3rd party]
WHERE [REFERENCE] Is Null OR [RATE] Is Null;
```